# openLDAP: login with userPrincipalName

Tags: active-directory, openldap

I have set up an `openLdap` server instance.

Login for the time being requires providing as username the user's `dn`, e.g.

`"cn=151test,cn=somecn,ou=someou,dc=mydomain,dc=com"`

How is it possible to enable login with `userPrincipalName` in the form of

`151test@mydomain.com` ?

**edit**: it seems that `userPrincipalName` is an attribute of `user` `objectClass`, available to **Active Directory** but not available out of the box to the default schema used by `openLDAP`.

So the question more or less becomes:

> how to use (import) an AD-compliant schema by (to) openLDAP **AND** enable login with `userPrincipalName` as username

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know using just the attribute value of `userPrincipalName` in a simple bind request only works for Microsoft-ActiveDirectory.

Other LDAP servers need the full-DN or a short DN if they are capable of bind-DN rewriting, like OpenLDAP's `slapd` with slapo-rwm.

Comment: Binding to a Microsoft Active Directory seems indeed to work, but I can't find any documentation on this. Do you happen to know any?